# Apache on kubernetes downlaods persistance volume files rather than rendering

Tags: apache, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

on k8s setup if I point Persistance storage volument to ngnix, it renders the media files corrects, where as same volume mounted to apache2 deployments downloads with headers instead of rendering. If the html folder is pointed to local ( instead of mounted volume ) it renders fine.
Even index.html will be downloaded and in text editor it shows the file contents with headers like this :

`s: bytes Content-Length: 5 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html`

Any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: Please add [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to answer your question without seeing your `Deployment`, `PV` and `PVC` definitions and without knowing your **apache** and **nginx** webservers configuration.

Comment: We encountered the same issue and adding <Directory />
EnableSendfile On
allow from all
</Directory> in apache2 config and then restarting apache solved the problem.